# EF IsModified = false still updating Underlyuing Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity that is in a Detached state. There are 2 fields on the entity 
that I DO NOT want to be updated. I am setting their IsModfied to false, but the properties are still updating in SQL SERVER. How can I force these columns not to update SQL SERVER?

```
if (Context.Entry(updatedFoo).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
   var oldEntity = Context.Foo.Find(updatedFoo.FooId);
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).Property(x => x.createdUserId).IsModified = false;
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).Property(x => x.createDateTime).IsModified = false;
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedSaving);
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

******EDIT*****

Seting an EntityState to modified over-writes all the Property level States that have been previously set.

If you set a state to modified and then set the individual properties on columns you will get the below error

**Additional information: Setting IsModified to false for a modified property is not supported**

Answer (score 4):

Flip the position of the statements:

```
if (Context.Entry(updatedFoo).State == EntityState.Detached)
{
   var oldEntity = Context.Foo.Find(updatedFoo.FooId);
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedSaving);
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).Property(x => x.createdUserId).IsModified = false;
   Context.Entry(oldEntity).Property(x => x.createDateTime).IsModified = false;
}
```

Because you set `IsModified` before you set the state of the object, every property is set as `IsModified = true`.

Comment: when I do that i Get 'Additional information: Setting IsModified to false for a modified property is not supported.'

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want those properties modified in the DB, then, why don't you avoid modifying them? If you do so, they won't be marked as changed.

I suppose you need to modify your `.SetValues` mathod to do so.

If you still want to modify those properties for some reason, do it after having called `.SaveChanges`, or even better, outside the `DbContext` scope. However, I can't see the reason to have an entity that differs from the DB.

Comment: "If you don't want those properties modified in the DB, then, why don't you avoid modifying them?"

In some cases this isn't possible without coming up with a solution that's more hacky than just using `IsModified`.

Comment: @TagC You should completely avoid introducing hacks in your code, unless they are unavoidable. That's my advice. I like "hack-free" code instead of "not-so-hacky" code. What is your case? I'm sure it has a non-hacky, easy solution. Of course, you can hammer a nail with a screwdriver, but I'd never recommend you using a hammer. Or a nail gun.

Comment: "unless they are unavoidable" It's unavoidable in our case. We get 95% of the data we require via event sourcing, but the team we rely on doesn't give us events for the remaining 5% so we have to make our system actively fetch that data from their database, which leads to all sorts of mess.